# How can I set securityContext for log4net programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, log4net

I am trying to set log4net securitycontext programmatically in the global.asax, but it doesn´t work. If I put this key in the web.config it works great, but i want to take those values from the database.

My web.config that works:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="FileAppenderGeneral" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="Logs\app.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="'.'dd" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%d %-5p - %m%n" />
  </layout>
  <<securityContext type="log4net.Util.WindowsSecurityContext">
    <domainName value="hostname"/>
    <userName value="username" />
    <password value="password" />
  </securityContext>
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
</appender>
```

My global.asax that not works:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        ILog[] loggers = LogManager.GetCurrentLoggers();
        foreach (ILog logger in loggers)
        {
            foreach (IAppender appender in logger.Logger.Repository.GetAppenders())
            {
                if (appender.GetType() == typeof(RollingFileAppender))
                {
                    log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender fileAppender = (RollingFileAppender)appender;
                    WindowsSecurityContext securityContext = new log4net.Util.WindowsSecurityContext();
                    securityContext.DomainName = "hostname";
                    securityContext.UserName = "username";
                    securityContext.Password = "password";
                    securityContext.ActivateOptions();
                    fileAppender.SecurityContext = securityContext;
                }
            }
        }
```

Any idea what am I doing bad in the global.asax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you need to create your own appender.

The log4net configuration file is just config for each logger that will be used in your applications. It means that you will need to 'programmatically' change security context for all your loggers. But here is a problem. You don't have all your loggers at the start of your application.

Therefore, you need to create your own appender and inherit it from the appender that you need. That's the only way to inject your own logic in log4net behavior.

Comment: Finnally I do that you say, create my appender in C# and not in web.config. Thnak you!!

Comment: Was glad to help!